# Finding volume of a solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I need to find the volume of the solid that is formed when the (x>0, y< -1) region of the curve y= -1/x is rotated about the y-axis.

If I'm correct, this volume can be calculated by:
Evaluating the definite integral (upper bound = -1, lower bound = -infinity) of π*(1/y²) with respect to y.

In evaluating this integral, I got up to:
Volume = (-π/1) - (-π/infinity)
       = -π

But how can a volume be a negative value?
Please let me know if I've done anything wrong, and explain how to get the correct answer if you can.

Thank you x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(-1/y²) should instead be (-1/y)². That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you! So is the correct answer Volume = π units^3 ?

Comment: Yes. Good work! If you are new to MSE  read through the tutorial. You should up vote and/or accept this answer if you consider it complete.